# I would like to change the value of two integer fields in sqlite db with button click

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am an android beginner and i am preparing for a university exam, only i have some difficulties with sqlite and the recyclerview. I would like to change the value of Integer fields using two buttons, when clicked the "EFFETTUATA" or "DISDETTA" field value becomes 1 instead of 0.
I have tried everything. This is my code:

```
DataBase:
public class PrenotazioniDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "prenotazioni.db";
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "elenco_prenotazioni";
   public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
   public static final String COL_2 = "NOME_CORSO";
   public static final String COL_3 = "NOME_PROFESSORE";
   public static final String COL_4 = "DATA";
   public static final String COL_5 = "ORA";
   public static final String COL_6 = "EFFETTUATA";
   public static final String COL_7 = "DISDETTA";


   public PrenotazioniDB(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOME_CORSO TEXT, NOME_PROFESSORE TEXT, DATA TEXT, ORA TEXT, EFFETTUATA INTEGER, DISDETTA INTEGER)");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
   }

   public boolean insertData(String name, String prof, String data, String ora, Integer eff, Integer dis) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
       contentValues.put(COL_3, prof);
       contentValues.put(COL_4, data);
       contentValues.put(COL_5, ora);
       contentValues.put(COL_6, eff);
       contentValues.put(COL_7, dis);
       long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
       if (result == -1) {
           System.out.println("errore");
           return false;
       } else {
           System.out.println(contentValues);
           return true;
       }
   }

   public ArrayList<BookingList> ReadAllData() {
       ArrayList<BookingList> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
       String query = "SELECT NOME_CORSO, NOME_PROFESSORE, DATA, ORA FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               BookingList bookingList = new BookingList();
               bookingList.setName(cursor.getString(0));
               bookingList.setProf(cursor.getString(1));
               bookingList.setData(cursor.getString(2));
               bookingList.setOra(cursor.getString(3));
               arrayList.add(bookingList);
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
       return arrayList;
   }

   public void deleteAll() {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME);
       db.close();
   }

   public Boolean checkDate(String data, String ora) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE DATA = ? AND ORA = ?", new String[]{data, ora});
       if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
}




ADAPTER WITH RECYCLER VIEW
public class BookingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookingAdapter.CoursesVH> {


   ArrayList<BookingList> prenotazioni;
   Context context;
   PrenotazioniDB db;


   public BookingAdapter(ArrayList<BookingList> prenotazioni, Context context) {
       this.prenotazioni = prenotazioni;
       this.context = context;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public BookingAdapter.CoursesVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
       CoursesVH chv = new CoursesVH(view);
       return chv;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CoursesVH holder, int position) {
       holder.nomeCorso.setText(prenotazioni.get(position).getName());
       holder.nomeProf.setText(prenotazioni.get(position).getProf());
       holder.dataCorso.setText(prenotazioni.get(position).getData());
       holder.oraCorso.setText(prenotazioni.get(position).getOra());
       db = new PrenotazioniDB(context);
   }



   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return prenotazioni.size();
   }

   class CoursesVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       TextView nomeCorso, nomeProf, dataCorso, oraCorso;
       Button wacthed, delete;
       LinearLayout layout;
       long id;

       public CoursesVH(@NonNull View v) {
           super(v);

           nomeCorso = v.findViewById(R.id.nomeCorso);
           layout = v.findViewById(R.id.layoutCard);
           nomeProf = v.findViewById(R.id.nomeProf);
           dataCorso = v.findViewById(R.id.dataCorso);
           oraCorso = v.findViewById(R.id.oraCorso);
           wacthed = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_watched);
           delete = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);



           wacthed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                     

                   }
           });

           delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                  
               }
           });

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a screenshot of what is happening? The question is not clear and also are you forced to use SQLiteOpenHelper? As it is a bit outdated and there is a good alternative which is Room database https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: @Amjad for the exam project I have to create an app to book lessons. I was able to have the user enter his reservation in the database and show his reservations in a recyclerview. But now I have to implement two methods to change the status of the reservation to "made" or "canceled". To do this I thought of inserting two integer fields in the db, as if they were Boolean values, and at the click of a button to change the value from 0 to 1. Based on the value of the two fields I would like to simply change the color of the card .

Comment: I got it . Can you dispense with SQLiteOpenHelper and use Room because it will greatly facilitate the matter for you

Comment: @Amjad thank you very much, but I have to use Sqlite. I just can't update a specific field.